# Auto indent C++11 lambda functions Vim

Tags: vim, c++, vimrc

Is there any way to get Vim to auto indent C++11 lambda functions correctly?

I have tried many different permutations of smartindent, cindent, etc. in .vimrc.

[image]

Comment: I think it's related to your standards such as old style C, camel case, and so on. please refer to your standard and adjust vim according to your standard,

Comment: Please, [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text). Are we supposed to re-type that complex code when testing?

Answer (score 1):

Here is piece of my `~/.vim/vimrc` configuration file:

```
set cindent           " enable specific indenting for C code
set cino+=j1,(0,ws,Ws " enable partial c++11 (lambda) support
```

Answer (score 0):

One workaround (not answer) is to declare the lambda and pass the func ptr into the receiving function... dilutes the convenience of lambdas though.